# Zend Framework Versions

Tags: zend-framework

What are the mapping of CE/PE/EE versions to corresponding Zend versions?

If possible I need a list going back before Magento 1.1.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Here is what I have. I hope it's enough. Because PE and EE versions can be related to CE versions I think you can figure out the missing values.

CE 1.0.19870.4  - ZF 1.5.1
CE 1.1.6        - ZF 1.5.1
CE 1.2.0.1      - ZF 1.7.2
CE 1.3.2.1      - ZF 1.7.2
CE 1.4.0.1      - ZF 1.9.6
CE 1.4.2.0      - ZF 1.10.8
CE 1.5 - CE 1.8 - ZF 1.11.1
CE 1.9          - ZF 1.12.3
CE 1.9.1.2      - ZF 1.12.10

PE 1.10         - ZF 1.11.1
PE 1.11         - ZF 1.11.1

EE 1.9.1.1      - ZF 1.10.8
EE 1.10 - 1.13  - ZF 1.11.1 
EE 1.14         - ZF 1.12.3

**[EDIT]**
To get the ZF version of your Magento instance look in the file `lib/Zend/Version.php`.
The class constant `VERSION` is what you are looking for.

Comment: @Marius — what was your methodology for determining zend framework version?

Comment: I'm curious of that, too. This is way more comprehensive than I could come up with.

Comment: There is no methodology. I have archives with the Magento versions listed in the answer. And I took a look in the file `lib/Zend/Version.php`. `Zend_Version::VERSION` gives you the ZF version.

Comment: CE 1.3.2.4 ZF 1.7.2

Comment: CE 1.8.1.0 ZF 1.11.1

Comment: CE 1.9.2.3 ZF 1.12.16

Comment: @Marius maybe time to make some updates here or move to wiki?

Comment: for magento2 check in - /vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Version.php