# Upgraded Zend causing problems?

Tags: magento-1.7, ce-1.7.0.2, zend-framework

I have discovered in a Magento CE 1.7.0.2 installation that I inherited that Zend apparently was upgraded at some point over the past year.  There have been a number of odd issues that have haunted me over the last couple months and I am curious as to whether or not replacing the `lib/Zend` package from a vanilla 1.7.0.2 installation can really bugger things up.

I am suspecting that it can, but I want to verify that here before I go replacing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each version of Magento is built to work on a specific ZF version.
(Off topic: [see a list of correspondence for some versions](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3440/zend-framework-versions/3443#3443))
It's not a good idea to upgrade ZF on your own.
This should be done by Magento Team (like it actually happens).
Changes in ZF can (and most probably will) affect the behavior of the application.
**A more general view**: Changing a CORE part of any application will impact the rest of the application (Duh...Captain Obvious).
This is somehow similar to the problem of extensions build for a Magento version that don't work for newer versions.
In conclusion ...**DO NOT UPGRADE ZF ON YOUR OWN**. If you do, be prepared for the worse.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. It appears in this particular case that the previous developers did not simply drop a new Zend in, but rather replaced it piecemeal.  While the version numbers match, the diffs of the file structure tell quite a different story.

Comment: Also causes similar grief when a "developer" decides to upgrade one of the javascript frameworks. Misery ensues.