# Is Magento planning on implementing Zend Framework 2?

Tags: zend-framework

Is Magento considering updating to ZF2? I understand ZF2 has been around for a few years. Why isn't it already using it?

Re: [Zend Framework Versions](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3440/zend-framework-versions)

Comment: good article to read - Magento 2 uses Zend Framework 1 (but it’s not that bad) http://magenticians.com/magento-2-uses-zend-1-not-that-bad

Comment: No, you're right, "it's not _that_ bad"... it's bloomin' awfully bad, slow and deprecated!

Comment: Rally not bad , specially about speed, check official answers and fresh community discussion http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/37024/why-arent-magento-developers-using-zend-framework-2-for-magento-2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't give you a 100% sure answer. Only the dev team can do that.
But I have a feeling that Magento 1.x will never ever use ZF2.
There are already too many things in the magento core that extend classed from ZF.
Changing to ZF2 will mean a lot of work that from my point of view is not justified.

Maybe in Magento 2, who knows.

Comment: I was around when ZF2 was being developed (I even contributed to core) and from what I saw, the ZF dev team copied regularly discussed and copied Symfony and ZF2 was rushed by the dev lead to meet a marketing deadline.

Answer (score 1):

Magento 1 will never use ZF2 and Magento 2 is build upon ZF1 too. And the item (to move from ZF1 to ZF2 for M2) was removed from the list afaik.

What Magento will do, as far as I understood my chats is, to remove Zend Framework from Magento and instead do their own stuff.

To be honest, there is not much left from ZF in Magento 1. I always complaint about "Magento is build upon Zend Framework"

Answer (score 1):

Today, you dont "implement" an existing framework, you only use components of it. The great about components is, that you dont depend on the major overall version, but instead can use single components of arbitary versions.

Nothing prevents you from using Zendframework2, the magento team already tryed it for the setup part, at least in the current dev release.

A fact is, they dont plan to build on the Zendframework Dependency Injection Container, as it does not perform for a project the size of Magento.

Equally they already "use" the Symfony2 Framework (the Yaml component), so you can tell all your entirely superficial friends, that Magento2 is build on Symfony2 now.

Comment: Everything noteworthy is being built upon symfony2 / silex components!